# What dspace field should I change to affect the way the Zotero connector works (e.g., change the item type that is filed through the connector)

Tags: dspace

I have been reading the documentation on DSPACE 7 and can't get it to work. The idea is to allow for different types of documents to be uploaded to DSPACE and benefit Zotero users from a connector that actually files all the relevant information in their personal database. By deafult, my DSPACE installation files all documents as "Journal Articles" (but my collection is mostly made of "Technical reports"). I have tried changing the `dspace.entity.type`, to no avail.